# Can't execute selectall on checkboxes with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I can't seem to figure out how to have another checkbox that selects all and deselects all boxes.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vxvch1xr/)

```
   <div ng-controller="tempCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAllOptions" ng-click="selectAll()" /> Select/Deselect All
    <li ng-repeat="t in parameters.myMainOptions.teams">
        <input ng-model="form.selectedTeams[t]" type="checkbox" />{{t}}</li>
    <button class="btn btn-sm" type="submit" ng-click="submit(form)">SUBMIT</button> <pre>
        {{form.selectedTeams}}
    </pre>

</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("tempCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.form = {
        selectedTeams: {}
    };
    $scope.parameters = {
        myMainOptions: {
            teams: ['angels', 'giants', 'orioles', 'bluejays', 'athletics']
        }
    };

    $scope.selectAll = function() {
         //This is where I'm stuck   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working plunkr of a simple select/deselect all checkbox:

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ma3RFaAmjoJnajlnid5q?p=info)

**Controller**

```
$scope.checkboxes = [
    {
      selected: false
    },
    {
      selected: false
    },
    {
      selected: false
    }
  ];

  // Check/uncheck all boxes
  $scope.checkAll = function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.checkboxes, function (obj) {
      obj.selected = $scope.selectAll;
    });
  };
```

**View**

```
<p>Check all</p>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />
  <br />
  <p>Checkboxes</p>
  <div ng-repeat="checkbox in checkboxes track by $index">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox.selected" />
    <label ng-show="checkbox.selected">Checkbox {{ $index+1 }} selected!</label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do `forEach` on `$scope.parameters.myMainOptions.teams` array and then set `$scope.form.selectedTeams` value in the loop. Also use `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`.

**Markup**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAllOptions" ng-change="selectAll()" />Select/Deselect All
<li ng-repeat="t in parameters.myMainOptions.teams">
    <input ng-model="form.selectedTeams[t]" type="checkbox" />{{t}}</li>
<button class="btn btn-sm" type="submit" ng-click="submit(form)">SUBMIT</button> <pre>
    {{form.selectedTeams}}
</pre>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.selectAll = function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.parameters.myMainOptions.teams, function (value, index) {
        $scope.form.selectedTeams[value] = $scope.selectAllOptions; //setting selectAll variable value
    })
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vxvch1xr/1/)

Comment: @KingKongFrog does it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make teams an array of objects like this

**Controller:**

```
   $scope.parameters = {
        myMainOptions: {
          teams: [{name: 'angels'}, {name: 'giants'}, {name: 'orioles'}, {name:'bluejays'}, {name: 'athletics'}]  
        }
    };
```

This is a better approach because, now, you can add a selected attribute to each team object.

Then you should set ng-model for each team checkbox to something like team.selected like this:

**View:**

```
<li ng-repeat="team in parameters.myMainOptions.teams">
        <input ng-model="team.selected" type="checkbox" />
        {{team}}
</li>
```

Now, if you check the angels checkbox, the object will change to `{name: 'angels', selected: true}`

Then your selectAll function will look like this:

**Controller:**

```
   $scope.selectAll = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.parameters.myMainOptions.teams, function (team) {
           team.selected = $scope.selectAllOptions;
        });
      };
```